# Is there a cheaper patent for low income applicants?

Tags: international, provisional-application, utility, cost, goverment

Is there a government supplement that offsets the cost of obtaining a patent for low income families?

Comment: Could you please explain what "cheapest patient funding and is homered internationally" means? I'm assuming you mean "patent" instead of "patient", but still I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: @EricShain  I m not entirely sure how patients work but are they cheaper in other countries? I am removing that part and just asking about the obama patent.

Comment: Patents are national so they only protect in the single country they are issued in.

Comment: I have made some small changes to your question which I think make it clearer. Please feel free to roll back if not however. In particular, I felt a bit uncomfortable providing an answer to whether you can get a cheaper "patient", since human trafficking is off-topic here I believe.

Comment: @Maca I invite you to make changes to any of my questions across SE and thanks

Comment: Maca’s answer is spot on. You can wait for other answers, but eventually it be great to select the best one by clicking on the check mark.

Comment: @EricShain I did. I am not sure how to file for that though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sort of, but only in the US (as far as I know).

You can file an application with micro entity status, which means most of the official fees are 75% less than the usual rate. This has some pretty strict requirements:

- No inventor/applicant is named on more than four previously filed applications.
- No inventor/application has a gross income more than three times the median household income preceding the year in which the fee is paid.
- No inventor/applicant has an obligation too assign a licence or ownership to someone who wouldn't meet the gross income test above.

If any of these change over time, you have to update your status. If you wrongly claim micro-entity status, your patent can be invalid. So it's a pretty big deal.

Comment: Show me how to file? I meet the requirements.

Comment: @Muze Although they don’t come free (usually) I’d suggest consulting with a patent attorney or agent. Patent agents may be less expensive. A patent needs to be written and prosecuted. Although it is possible to do this by oneself, the likelihood of success is much lower. Even if you manage to get a patent, without expert help, it very well might be of low quality and not very useful.

Comment: @EricShain do you think this SE site can increase the quality and success if I take all the advise?

Comment: @Muze How to file would need to be a separate question, since it's far too involved for a comment. The USPTO has some reasonable guides out about how to do so, I believe. But in any case Eric Shain is right, a patent attorney is the best option if you want a worthwhile patent.