# Step by step walk through for a United States low income patient

Tags: patent-applications, provisional-application

How do I apply for the patent process mentioned in the below question's answer? Can someone guide me on how to do this?

[Is there a cheaper patent for low income applicants?](https://patents.stackexchange.com/questions/19353/is-there-a-cheaper-patent-for-low-income-applicants)

I understand that I am asking for much. I believe this will help many people.

Comment: I think you mean “patent” not “patient”. Whole books have been written about how to obtain a patent. I suggest you search on Amazon. In any case applying is easy compared to actually drafting and processing an application.

Comment: I think your best bet if you want to do this without a lawyer is: https://www.amazon.com/Patent-Yourself-Step-Step-Filing/dp/1413325394/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1532789935&sr=8-2&keywords=patent+it+yourself.

Comment: @EricShain  Looks like a good answer.

Comment: I hate answering with a non-answer. However I don't think this question is answerable in this format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are including the steps of writing the patent then, as Eric Shain posted, the answer is at least book-length. The book Patent it Yourself is a good start.  If you are asking just about the mechanics of filing, that is a shorter answer. If that is the question, I would suggest that you edit your question or submit another question.

Taking the question more broadly - the USPTO has a reduced fee schedule for what it calls micro entities. The primary way of qualifying is based on income. Most fees are cut in half from the fees for "small entities". They also sponsor a [pro bono  program](https://www.uspto.gov/patents-getting-started/using-legal-services/pro-bono/pro-bono-program-independent-inventors-and) that might match you with a local patent attorney who could work with you at no charge. They do not take everyone who applies.